# cv_bridge in conda environment

Tags: cv-bridge, anaconda

I want to use `cv_bridge` in a conda environment. It works well in base environment but not in the conda environment. I am getting the following error :

```
from cv_bridge.boost.cv_bridge_boost import getCvType
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
```

I tried installing the package using `dpkg` but it still didnt work. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the exact same issue with `cv_bridge` inside a conda environment (Ubuntu 20.04, ROS Noetic, Python 3.8 env).

The workaround that works for me is to instead use [ros-numpy](https://github.com/eric-wieser/ros_numpy) when I want to convert an `Image` message from ROS to a numpy array. You can then do other transformations on it as needed. Do note that since its dependent on ROS, you need to install it by either `sudo apt install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-numpy` or cloning to your workspace.

Example:

```py
# im = self.cv_bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(rgb_image_message) # Earlier version
im = ros_numpy.numpify(rgb_image_message)
```

Comment: Ohh thanks!Do i publish this like a normal msg then?

Comment: Yes, sure! It can also be used to convert the array back to a ros message. In the above example, if you want to re-publish the `im` numpy array back as an `Image` message, then you can do: 

`img_msg = ros_numpy.msgify(Image, im, encoding='bgr8')` 

You can change the encoding depending on the image type (depth, rgb, bgr etc).  More examples are shown in the [ros-numpy README](https://github.com/eric-wieser/ros_numpy#readme).

Comment: Hi , im getting an error saying in ros_numpy has no attribute msgify() , and i checked the list of functions in the module and it only has ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a ROS package like `cv_bridge` in a conda environment with conda-forge packages, a possible option is to install ROS itself directly in the conda environment with [RoboStack](https://robostack.github.io/), i.e. running:

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c robostack-staging ros-noetic-cv-bridge
```

if you are using Noetic or

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c robostack-staging ros-humble-cv-bridge
```

if you are using Humble.

In general, your problem is related to the fact that you can't mix apt packages (like cv_bridge in your case) and conda packages (as Python). Similar problem may happen if you try to mix conda packages from `conda-forge` and from the `defaults`/`anaconda` channel, as in general they are not ABI compatible. RoboStack packages are only ensured to be ABI compatible with conda-forge packages.